# modificar la sección del head desde el código de un componente Joomla

Tags: joomla3

Tengo que insertarle el código de Google Analitycs (que son 2 etiquetas script) en el head de mi pagina, pero no se donde colocarlo ya que los componentes con Joomla se crean de forma individual, y la verdad no se donde ponerlo sin que se me rompa toda la pagina.
Creo entender que en "**libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php**" agregas `$doc->addScript("$RUTA-FICHERO-JS/FICHERO.JS")` y se agrega. Pero si alguien me pudiera confirmar si efectivamente es así o no, les agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Explora las opciones de tu la plantilla que estás utilizando casi la gran mayoría trae un campo para agregar scripts, etc.

Y si lo quieres hacer de forma manual depende de cómo esté construida tu plantilla por lo que tendrás que explorar. Normalmente

**templates/tuplatilla/template/header.php**
o
**templates/tuplatilla/index.php**